# Packet of cards and probability

Tags: probability

The packet of 10 cards includes 4 aces and cards: 5,6,7,8,9 and 10.

What is the probability that:

1. Four randomly chosen cards are consecutive numbers.
2. In the four of randomly chosen cards isn't any ace.
3. In the four of randomly chosen cards are two aces and two consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** There are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to choose a "hand" of $4$ cards from the $10$.  All hands are equally likely.  So to answer the three questions, all we need to do is to *count* the hands that qualify, and divide each count by $\binom{10}{4}$.  The numbers are small, we could count by making  careful lists.

$1.$  How many hands have $4$ consecutive cards? Surely we can list them all, without any theory. There is $\{5,6,7,8\}$, and $\{6,7,8,9\}$, and $\{7,8,9,10\}$.

$2.$  How many aceless hands are there? We need to *choose* $4$ cards from the $6$ non-aces.

$3.$ We can choose the $2$ Aces in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  For **each** of these ways, the two consecutives can be chosen in $5$ ways.